# Textmate alt-f to move forward by one word

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, textmate, keybindings

I've recently switched from Linux to Mac. One thing that is really killing my emacs memory muscles right now is the lack of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to jump forward and backward by word.

I've gotten the meta/option flag flipped in Terminal.app preferences (so <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> now works as expected), but I haven't found a similar option for Textmate. Even better if I could enable it as a MacOS  global setting for the U.S. keyboard (so it would work in all input boxes). At the moment I get the following useless (for me) encodings:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>: ƒ

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>: ∫

How do I remap <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to jump forward and backward by word?

Comment: Thanks Am1rr3zA for pointing out how to style keyboard shortcuts; that looks much better. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual... [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) to the rescue :P   Its emacs mode will give you those bindings, and you can choose a lot more bindings than that as well:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

FYI, it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the Mac shortcuts list, but on my Macbook Air you can press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

to move forward and backward one word, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

One way to remap the keys in other applications as well would be to create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "~b" = moveWordBackward:;
    "~f" = moveWordForward:;
    "~d" = deleteWordForward:;
    "~l" = (moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:, lowercaseWord:);
    "~u" = (moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:, uppercaseWord:);
    "~c" = (moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:, capitalizeWord:);
}
```

You could also `cp /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict ~/Libary/Application\ Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict` and add the same keys there.